# not able to protect the python flask rest api service using keycloak

Tags: python, keycloak, flask-oidc

I have keycloak server running in docker (192.168.99.100:8080) and python flask-oidc flask application running locally ( localhost:5000)  i am not able to access the protected Rest Api even after getting the access_token.  has anyone tried this code. if so please help me regarding this. thank you

[this is my keycloak client using docker jboss/keycloak image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG1TQ.png)

[this is my newuser under the new realm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7m88.png)

below is my flask-application

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, g  
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect  
import requests

secret_key = os.urandom(24).hex()  
print(secret_key)  
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS"]="client_secrets.json"  
app.config["OIDC_COOKIE_SECURE"]=False  
app.config["OIDC_SCOPES"]=["openid","email","profile"]
app.config["SECRET_KEY"]=secret_key  
app.config["TESTING"]=True  
app.config["DEBUG"] = True  
app.config["OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE"]=False  
app.config["OIDC_REQUIRED_VERIFIED_EMAIL"]=False  
app.config["OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD"]='client_secret_post'  
app.config["OIDC_USER_INFO_ENABLED"]=True  

oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)  
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
if oidc.user_loggedin:
    return ('Hello, %s, <a href="/private">See private</a> '
            '<a href="/logout">Log out</a>') % \
           oidc.user_getfield('preferred_username')
else:
    return 'Welcome anonymous, <a href="/private">Log in</a>'
```

**client_secrets.json**

```
{
"web": {
    "issuer": "http://192.168.99.100:8080/auth/realms/kariga",
    "auth_uri": "http://192.168.99.100:8080/auth/realms/kariga/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "client_id": "flask-app",
    "client_secret": "eb11741d-3cb5-4457-8ff5-0202c6d6b250",
    "redirect_uris": [
        "http://localhost:5000/"
    ],
    "userinfo_uri": "http://192.168.99.100:8080/auth/realms/kariga/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo", 
    "token_uri": "http://192.168.99.100:8080/auth/realms/kariga/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "token_introspection_uri": "http://192.168.99.100:8080/auth/realms/kariga/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
}
}
```

when i launch the flask-app in web browser
i click on the **Log in** link
next it prompts for the **user details** (user created under my new realm)
it takes a couple of seconds then it redirects me to an error page
http://localhost:5000/oidc_callback?state=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjogIkZZbEpqb3ZHblZoUkhEbmJsdXhEVW
that says

**httplib2.socks.HTTPError**

**httplib2.socks.HTTPError: (504, b'Gateway Timeout')**

and also it is redirecting to /oidc_callback which is not mentioned anywhere
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is occuring because **keycloak** server which is running
in **docker**(**192.168.99.100**)
 is not able to hit the **flask application** server which is running locally(**localhost**)

better to run both as **services** in **docker** by creating a **docker-compose** file